# How to check state of checkbox using selenium if 'checked' attribute is not available to use the isChecked / isSelected?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How to check if checkbox is checked or not checked using selenium without jQuery/JScript if 'checked' attribute is not available to use the `isChecked` / `isSelected`?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you should try to toggle the checkbox while you are in developer mode in order to see which element or attribute is changed during the toggle process. When you find out which thing is changed ,you can used that to check by selenium.

Answer (score 0):

Checkboxes don't always have the `checked` attribute, you can still use `isSelected()` on it.